Grouping existing Age category to a different spec
I have a dataset with a Age field. This field contains a text value that describes an Age range : 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, 20-24, 25-29, etc. Each row has a TotalPeople column, who are in that Age group.
I would like to regroup this data slightly so the age group is : 0-9, 10-19, 20-29. And return the SUM of TotalPeople in that group.
I wonder can anyone advise me please?
Thanking you
I tried regrouping the Age in a CTE. I'm getting compilation errors.

If you are close what have you tried?  It also helps if you can provide repeatable example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Though you can look into a CASE statement in your select and if case is either of the 2 you want to join, then sum those totals up.

^^^ case expression

The editor supports table markdown which makes data a whole lot easier to read

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can do a case when AgeColumn IN ('0-4', '5-9') then '0-9' when ... end

thank you everyone. It is a CASE statement. I was getting confused and attempting a CTE route - not necessary as you all pointed out
